# How to pass control from one tkinter window to another?

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

I am trying to communicate to arduino using python 3.6.4. I have two tkinter windows. When I press a button on the first window, the second window opens. I would give some numerical inputs in the second window. These numerical inputs correspond to a digital pin in the arduino which is connect to LED's. I am trying to pass these value to the arduino through serial library in python. But I could not pass the value from the second window. Does anyone know how to pass the entire control from one tkinter window to another? Any insight would be helpful. I am a beginner in python programming. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use simpledialog? Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()

def input_int():
    result = simpledialog.askinteger('Integers', 'Enter a numerical value')
    print(result)

get = tk.Button(root, text='Get', command=input_int)
get.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir, That was really helpful.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it was helpful.